Can't import Drizzle package in NestJS
I'm having trouble importing a package from mysql2/promise into NestJS project. I was following official documentation
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/mysql2";
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";
import * as schema from './schema';

export const DrizzleAsyncProvider = 'drizzleProvider';

export const drizzleProvider = {
  provide: DrizzleAsyncProvider,
  useFactory: async () => {
    console.log(mysql, '<<<');

    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'host',
      user: 'user',
      database: 'database',
      password: 'password'
    });
    const db = drizzle(connection, { schema, mode: 'default' });

    return db;
  },
  exports: [DrizzleAsyncProvider],
}

For some reason, I'm getting next error:
[Nest] 16326  - 04/20/2024, 8:31:46 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
undefined <<<
[Nest] 16326  - 04/20/2024, 8:31:46 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createConnection')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createConnection')


Drizzle docs seem to be outdated. Please try this:
import * as mysql from "mysql2/promise";


Typescript as default has allowSyntheticDefaultImports , unfortunately if the transpiler is not configure to inject to default export, TS won't complain but you get these runtime errors, it's for this reason I just stick with import * as X in all my code with Typescript, and setting allowSyntheticDefaultImports to false would avoid using this feature.

In the documentation, you need to also install mysql2, as they stated:
pnpm add drizzle-orm mysql2
pnpm add -D drizzle-kit

I replicated your exact code snippet, and it works fine. Just make sure you have mysql2 installed.

Sadly, that's not the case. Everything is installed, and I'm able to go inside 'mysql2/promise' package in my IDE. I've just removed package-lock and node_modules and reinstalled everything. Still the same problem
